# SQL subtraction within a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im creating a view as the following:

```
create view newView as 

select custName,City, Zip, CreditLimit - Balance as total
from Customer
where Rep = '70';
```

the problem im having is with subtracting two columns and adding the value into a new column named total.

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?  The syntax looks okay.

Comment: And what is the error message ?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure newView, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: all the columns are in the base table Customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reason because I just verified it:

You are trying to run the view with a SELECT statement in the same query window in which your CREATE VIEW statement is located because that won't work and you will get the error message you indicated. CREATE the view in a separate window and use a clear window to test it with a SELECT statement

I'm not referring to the SELECT statement that creates the View but when I added a SELECT statement below the create view in my own query window to test the view that is when I got the same error you reported.

**Example**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the create view statement.  Are you able to run just the select statement?

```
select custName,City, Zip, (CreditLimit - Balance) as total
  from Customer
 where Rep = '70';
```

I'm guessing one of the columns maybe missing from the base table.